# automapper Ivalueresolver using DI in constructor

Tags: c#, .net-core, automapper

Basically I got the same as: [Asp.net core 2.0 AutoMapper IValueResolver dependency injection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49440305/asp-net-core-2-0-automapper-ivalueresolver-dependency-injection)

but there was no answer.

So i got:

```
public static void AddMapperConfiguration(this IServiceCollection services)
{
    var spb = services.BuildServiceProvider();

    var mapperConfiguration = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
    {
        cfg.AddProfile<CmsDataMappingProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<ClsMappingProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<ClsMockDataMappingProfile>();
        cfg.AddProfile<LpisMappingProfile>();

        cfg.AllowNullCollections = true;
        cfg.AllowNullDestinationValues = true;
        cfg.ConstructServicesUsing(spb.GetService); //read it the other post
    });

    mapperConfiguration.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
    services.AddSingleton<IMapper>(sp => new Mapper(mapperConfiguration)); //just testing
}
```

and as resolver:

```
public class CurrencyResolver : IValueResolver<List<VehicleAndQuote>, LeasingPlan, List<Duration>>
{
    private readonly ICountryProfileConnector _countryProfileConnector;

    public CurrencyResolver(ICountryProfileConnector countryProfileConnector)
    {
        _countryProfileConnector = countryProfileConnector;
    }

     ....left out for readability
}
```

and thoughts? I'm getting the no parameterless constructor error on this.

thnx!

Comment: https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection

Comment: the post is long and i was missing some information. Turns out only `services.AddAutoMapper()` does the trick. Thnx. However, now i am getting an error on one of the nested mapping. it was like `... .ForMember(catalogVehicle => catalogVehicle.VehicleSpecification, src => src.MapFrom(vehicleAndQuote => vehicleAndQuote));` and then in the profile i've `CreateMap<VehicleAndQuote, VehicleSpecification>()..formembers etc..`
is that changed?

Comment: Make sure you pass types or assemblies to AddAutomapper. And also that you inject IMapper, not use the static Mapper.